# Can't run app. java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I trying to reanimate a very very old project from year 2016. After upgrading gradle plugin, gradlew-wrapper, databinding imports and a lot of other problems referenced with project updating, I became able to run the app. But when I try to run the app, my build is interrupting with the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

If I run same build with --stacktrace option, I get this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.gradle.internal.exceptions.DefaultMultiCauseException.printSingleCauseStackTrace(DefaultMultiCauseException.java:143)
    at org.gradle.internal.exceptions.DefaultMultiCauseException.printStackTrace(DefaultMultiCauseException.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.event.types.DefaultFailure.fromThrowable(DefaultFailure.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.event.types.DefaultFailure.fromThrowable(DefaultFailure.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.event.types.DefaultFailure.fromThrowable(DefaultFailure.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientForwardingTaskOperationListener.toTaskResult(ClientForwardingTaskOperationListener.java:125)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientForwardingTaskOperationListener.toFinishedEvent(ClientForwardingTaskOperationListener.java:91)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientForwardingTaskOperationListener.toFinishedEvent(ClientForwardingTaskOperationListener.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubtreeFilteringBuildOperationListener.finished(SubtreeFilteringBuildOperationListener.java:96)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubtreeFilteringBuildOperationListener.finished(SubtreeFilteringBuildOperationListener.java:98)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientForwardingProjectConfigurationOperationListener.finished(ClientForwardingProjectConfigurationOperationListener.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationListenerManager$ProgressShieldingBuildOperationListener.finished(DefaultBuildOperationListenerManager.java:127)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationListenerManager$1.finished(DefaultBuildOperationListenerManager.java:60)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$ListenerAdapter.stop(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:170)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$BuildOperationTrackingListener.stop(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:229)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:372)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:359)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:352)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
```

But problem is still not clarified.

I already tried:

- delete `.gradle` directory inside of my project
- delete `.idea`
- delete `.gradle/caches` of entire android on my computer
- Options above + Invalidate cahces and Restart, reimport project, make project, sync project, reopen Android Studio

All these options didn't help me

Comment: try command gradlew build --info to see detailed error

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed --info option and --debug option didn't show more details

Comment: try to update Gradle version in Gradle wrapper file and Gradle plugin

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed those versions are already up-to-date